# Smart Maps problems displaying static maps

Tags: plugin-smartmap, google-maps

I'm trying to output a static map from a smart map field in a matrix. I can output a dynamic map with no issues, but the static map code isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
{% set locations = entry.locationsAndNotes %}
{% set options = {
    width: 370,
    height: 208,
    zoom: 16,
} %}
{{ craft.smartMap.img(locations[0], options) }}
```

The url it outputs looks like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?visual_refresh=true&key=myKey&scale=2&center=-48.876667,-123.393333&size=370x208&maptype=roadmap&zoom=16
Pasted into a browser, i get an error that the API server rejected my request because it is missing the size parameter.

If I change all of the `&amp` to &, an image loads, but it's just a blank blue map.

It seems like this should work, since I can render a dynamic map, but I'm not sure if it's an issue with my code, or the plugin, or the api.

Comment: If you change `craft.smartMap.img` to `craft.smartMap.map`, you're saying it loads the dynamic map properly? Does the marker appear in the correct spot?

Comment: @LindseyD Yes, changing it to craft.smartMap.map loads the dynamic map with the marker in the correct spot.

Comment: Looks like a bug... contact support@doublesecretagency.com.

Comment: for anyone else that comes across this issue in the future - I ran into the same problem, and I needed to a) generate a google-maps API key and b) *enable certain APIs* in the google api settings - do the stuff on this page: https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/get-google-api-keys/ - the Google Static Maps API is *not* enabled by default.